# WordPress Multiple Themes for Single Website

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I’ve been experiencing a problem that I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.  In an effort to make my website more mobile friendly, I purchased a mobile responsive theme.  While I know I could have created a sub-domain or a directory to house the mobile version of the website, I’ve been attempting to have the original domain http://example.com switch themes based on the user.  In other words, for http://example.com, Desktop user views DesktopTheme and Mobile user views MobileTheme.  With the Any Mobile Theme Switcher plugin, I was able to accomplish this will little issue.  However, for certain pages I would like to be able to display the desktop version to the mobile user.  For example, for single posts, I would like the desktop user and the mobile user both to see the DesktopTheme.

Unfortunately, after several hours of searching and experimenting I am not further along than when I started.  Using different templates appeared to be an option, but it’s not a true theme switch.  When I altered the template files, mobile users received a hybrid version of the site that includes the mobile header and an unstructured version of the desktop version.  A similar result was achieved when I simply copied the single.php file from DesktopTheme into the folder for MobileTheme.

Example:

```
<?php get_header('/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/DesktopTheme/header.php'); ?>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin that you can use for switching themes based on the post type as well as a lot of other conditions:

http://codecanyon.net/item/wordpress-theme-switcher/558740

I'm not aware of any free version that offers the same functionality, but that doesn't mean one doesn't exist.

With that said, I think you should reconsider your approach here. The entire point of responsive design is so you do not have to have separate mobile and desktop sites. I think you should sidestep this entire issue by using the responsive theme everywhere.

Using a single responsive theme is going to make maintenance much easier and give the user a more consistent experience.

Also, `get_header` is meant to load a header file from the current theme. You can't load components from other themes and expect them to work correctly.